# Error Occured running Grails CLI: repo.grails.org: Name or service not known

Tags: grails

I get this error when I try running `grails` on linux:

```
Error Occured running Grails CLI: repo.grails.org: Name or service not known
```

Comment: can you please provide more logs and details like version etc.

Comment: Grails Version:3.1.10, Groovy Version 2.4.7, JVM Version 1.7.0_101